# Check current state of child process (not change of state)

Tags: c, linux

I want to check whether a child process is currently stopped or not (I'm using ptrace). Using `waitpid` with `NOHANG` doesn't work, because that only checks for a *change* of state since last time, not the current state. It would simply return 0 if the state is unchanged (which might mean running, stopped, anything).

Is there some function for this in Linux that I can use from C? I know I can check it by reading `/proc/PID/status`, but I'd rather not do that directly in a C program.

I want to be able to run:

```
if(is_stopped(pid)) {}
if(is_stopped(pid)) {}
```

right after each other, even if the state didn't change.

Comment: C does not have a concept of concurrent processes.

Comment: I don't think there is a portable way, but you mention `/proc`, so if you want to restrict yourself to operating systems that have `/proc` such as Linux and Solaris, you can do that. `/proc` has nothing to do with Bash, by the way, so your second paragraph is a non sequitur.

Comment: Maybe try `PTRACE_GETREGS` and see if it succeeds or if it fails with `ESRCH`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thanks, I might resort to it, but ESRCH has also other meanings, like that the process doesn't exist.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe try waitpid with WNOHANG after the ptrace with PTRACE_GETREGS fails; it will tell you if the process exists (and if it is still your child).

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I used your solution and it works quite nice - you can add it as an answer if you want.

Comment: Since you have working code, I invite you to supply it as an answer; that would be better for future readers of this question than any example code I could come up with.